# Prawn+Rails: How to set all even pages blank

Tags: pdf, prawn

I'm generating PDF using Prawn. I need to display the content only in Odd pages and leave the Even pages blank so it can be printed one-sided.

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: You'd do that in the next production step, your printer (be it a device or a person) should be able to this. Doing it earlier would mess with your page numbering.